# Submit button not redirecting to results.php properly

Tags: php, forms

I have an assessment form that I need to submit to a results.php that calculates the score and gives a response. However whenever I hit the submit button, it just redirects to assessment/results.php which shows page not found. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
<form action="results.php" method="post" id="assessment">
<!-- Question 1 BLUE -->
<div class="evaluation_question">Sometimes I feel and experience moments of anger "out of the blue".</div>
<div class="evaluation_answers">
        <span class="answer_choice">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_button" name="question1" id="question1_1" value="True" />
            <label class="radio_label" for="question_1">True</label>
        </span>
        <span class="answer_choice">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_button" name="question1" id="question1_2" value="False" />
            <label class="radio_label" for="question_2">False</label>
        </span>
            <input type="radio" style="display: none;" name="question1" id="question1_none" checked="checked" value="" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitbtn" />
</form>
```

Here is the code from the results.php page:

```
<?php
            
    $blueAnswer1 = $_POST['question1'];

    $blueTotal = 0;

    if ($blueAnswer1 == "True") { $blueTotal++; }

    echo "<div id='results'>$blueTotal /  Scoring Explanation</div>";

?>
```

Comment: What folder is `results.php` located in relation to the page with the form? Maybe your form tag needs to read `<form action="../results.php"...>`.

Comment: @kmoser They are both in /wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone

Comment: What exact URLs are the page with the form and the `results.php` page? (You can omit the domain; the important thing is the paths.)

Comment: @kmoser I actually was able to get it resolved by setting up a results page and change the action path to results instead of results.php. Working well now.